# How can i pass <SelectListItem> text in a DropDownList to another view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I cannot figure out how to pass the text from a `<SelectListItem>` with a DropDownList from one view to another.

I am using the following in a view:

```
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost())
{ 
    @Html.Hidden("myData", new MvcSerializer().Serialize(Model, SerializationMode.Signed))
    ...
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyProperty, new SelectList(Model.MyPropertyList, "Value", "Text"))
    ...
}
```

In my ViewModel (MyData), I have:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyData
{
public int MyProperty{ get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MyPropertyList{ get; set; }
...
public MyData()
    {
        var mypropertylist = new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "(Please select)" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text="Some text." },                
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text="Some other text." }
            };
        this.MyPropertyList = mypropertylist; //Edited
    }
}
```

I am using a wizard and want to pass the data collected in one step to either the confirmation page or an e-mail my code generates.

For example, if I do `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)` in a view, I can pass that input into a confirmation view by doing `@Model.FirstName`.

I have RadioButtons for which I am able to do the following: `@Html.Raw(MyNamespace.ViewModels.MyModel.MyPropertyDictionary.mypropertyDictionary[Model.MyProperty])` to pass the data to my confirmation view. But I am unable to properly create the `@Html.Raw` (assuming that's what I'd have to do) for a DropDown.

Thanks!

**UPDATE (To add controller code per comment request):**

Controller:

```
private MyData myData;
....
//
// STEP 1:
// AskUs
public ActionResult AskUsDetails(string nextButton)
{
    if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("AskUsSubmitted");
    return View("AskUs/Details", myData);
}
//
// STEP 2:
// AskUs/Submitted
public ActionResult AskUsSubmitted()
{
    // Todo: Save myData database; render a "Submitted" view
    MyMailer.AskUs(myData).Send();
    return View("AskUs/Submitted", myData);
}
```

Things to note:

1. There is a serialization part to the controller. I don't know if its relevant (let me know if it is and I will edit inside the code above).
2. Using MvcMailer, so there are 2 other files involved, but again I don't know if its relevant (it's the `MyMailer.AskUs(myData).Send();` part above).

**UPDATE:**

If I do `@Model.MyPropertyList` in the confirmation view, my view shows

```
System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]
```

If I use `@Model.MyProperty` I am getting the value, e.g.,

```
1
```

I just need to figure out how to output the actual "Text" contained, for example, in

```
new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text="**Some text.**" }
```

Any examples of how to do that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can we see your controller code?

Comment: @iaimtomisbehave Updated to put controller code - let me know if there's anything else you need to see. Much appreciated

Comment: See my DDL tutorials http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Checking the links now, thanks! They are relatively new, probably why they didn't come up on searches.

Comment: After reviewing and trying to implement the code from the above links Rick provided I've concluded that his solutions won't work in my context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form containing a dropdown list, only the selected value is sent to the server. If you wanted to fetch the corresponding text you could use this selected value and search into the corresponding list.

Also you don't need to manually add the `(Please select)` item to your collection. This could be done in the view directly:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.MyProperty, 
    Model.MyPropertyList, 
    "(Please select)"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip about inserting text in the view directly. I'm still struggling with syntax for outputting the value. If I do `@Model.MyPropertyList` in the confirmation view, my view shows `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]`. If I use `@Model.MyProperty` I am getting the value, e.g., `1`.

Comment: @REMESQ, replace the following line in your view: `this.MyPropertyList = new SelectList(mypropertylist , "Value", "Text");` by `this.MyPropertyList = mypropertylist;` or directly initialize it. You don't need to use a `SelectList` because you already have an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. It's redundant.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I posted code I changed recently, so yes, I have 'this.MyPropertyList = mypropertylist;' now. Editing above.

Comment: I have been struggling to get something working using your advice about fetching the corresponding text. May I impose upon you to provide an example?

Comment: @REMESQ, what are you trying to achieve? You need an example of what?

Comment: Based on my DropDownListFor, you mentioned in your answer that only the selected value is sent to the server (hence why in my confirm view I only see the value selected, e.g. "1"). You also suggested that if I wanted to fetch the corresponding text I could use the selected value and search into the corresponding list. I have been trying to figure out how to do exactly that (assuming its possible).

Comment: @REMESQ, sure, in your POST action you will simply query your repository (which presumably will query your database or something) to get you the corresponding text given the selected value, just like that: `string selectedText = Repository.GetText(selectedValue);`.

Answer (score 0):

To just display the Text from the SelectListItem that corresponds with the @Model.MyProperty value you can use

```
@{
    var item = Model.PropertyList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value == Model.MyProperty.ToString());
    var itemText = item.Text;                            
}

@itemText
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//controller
TempData["TaxType"] = act.GetTaxType();



//view
 @foreach (var item in (List<SelectListItem>) TempData["TaxType"])
            {
                <option value="@item.Value" >@item.Text</option>
            }
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer. Why does this work? What was the issue that you resolved? That makes it easier for OP and everyone in the future to understand their problem.